# Quering XML embedded code from SSRS

Tags: xml, reporting-services, xml-parsing, ssrs-2008, xquery

I have XML embedded data and I'm querying it from SSRS using XML data provider, I'm using the XML Query and Element Path to query the data and code from SSRS Data set, here is my data structure in the Data set:

```
<Query>
<XmlData>
<Customers>
<Customer>
<CustomerType>Peopole</CustomerType>
<FirstName>Bobby</FirstName>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<CustomerType>Org</CustomerType>
<FirstName>Crystal</FirstName>
</Customer>
</Customers>
</XmlData>
<ElementPath>Customers/Customer</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

I need to get only the customer of type People, what should be written in the element path tag to return the people type only ??

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the SSRS engine does not allow you to filter rows based on an element's value.

"The query language supported through the XML data provider resembles the XML Path language (XPATH). However, there are both syntactical and behavioral differences between the two languages. ***Perhaps the most notable difference is the lack of querying and filtering support***"

(source:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129(v=sql.90).aspx)

The easiest way I've found to filter an xml dataset is to use a dataset filter.  Right click on your dataset, select "Filters" from the left-hand column, and set your column CustomerType=People as your filter.  That will filter the dataset based on an element value for you.